Hotspot connection SSH / Ping
I have a singleboard computer (Rock 4 SE) with a wifi that is hotspot capable. It is running linux Debian. I want to SSH into it with my laptop using the linux machines own wifi as a hotspot for connection. I created a hotspot on the linux machine, gave it a name and password and started up the hotspot.
My laptop (Win 11) is able to locate the hotspot and i can connect to it.
I ran ip a to find out the address of the linux machine which turned out to be 10.42.0.1/24.
However, when I try to ping the address from my laptop using powershell ping 10.42.0.1 all I get is:

PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Trying ssh <hostname>@10.42.0.1 gives a timeout error. The ssh is up and running when checked on the linux machine.
Also when running nmap -sn 10.42.0.1/24 on the linux machine it returns:

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (1host up) scanned in 2.73 seconds
As if it would not see my laptop on the network.

Is there any idea how to connect the two machines with the hotspot so that they can communicate with each other?
Please note that I don´t want any internet connection shared in this ordeal. I just want to connect the two machines together with SSH using the hotspot of one machine.
